Find improper use of log method inside catch block
I attempted to solve this issue in this question previously, but attempts at using a plain regex didn't quite work.
In a project I'm working on, log methods provide the following
public static void info(Object source, String message)
public static void info(Object source, String message, Throwable t)

for various logging levels.
However, the methods have been used incorrectly, in a way that doesn't log all the information.
// Bad example 1
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops");
}

// Bad example 2
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops " + e);
}

// Bad example 3
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops " + e.getMessage());
}

// Correct usage
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops", e);
}

// Also correct
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops", e);
    Log.info(this, "also doing this other thing");
}

// Technically correct specifically for ignored, but should probably be logged anyway
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception ignored) {
    Log.error(this, "oops");
}

// Technically correct, but rarely seen and should probably be changed anyway
try {
    // something
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.error(this, "oops");
    throw new OtherException(e);
}

The bad examples have been a cause for headaches when debugging, as the full exception isn't included in the log.
My question is: how can I find all cases where a log line is used incorrectly within a catch block? Namely, where the exception is used neither as a parameter to a log method, nor as a cause to the rethrown exception. The question linked above attempted to find these using regex but most solutions suggested had a fairly high failure rate (either matching too many correct usages or not matching all incorrect usages).
I'm using Intellij as my IDE, so if it has any tools that would be useful in achieving this that would also be good to know.
Additionally, this is a large and old project. Directly refactoring the Log methods may be too much effort; a find-and-replace would be best but all options can be considered.
Edit: tools that rely on using a log4j.Logger,  java.util.logging.Logger, or similar for analysis don't apply here, since this is a custom Log class that provides static methods for logging.

I wonder if it might be better to create your own logging util that only has the correct forms, and which calls Log.whatever underneath the hood. Then you could just find any direct usages of Log.

@David good idea, but Log.info(this, "everything is fine") is also valid if you're just logging state. The difficulty lies in enforcing the correct state specifically within a catch block, although sometimes even those get complicated enough that the correct form might only be used once.

Ah, yes, I see now.


Add sonarlint plugin to Intellij
Scan your code
Find all warnings https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/RSPEC-1166 "Either log this exception and handle it, or rethrow it with some contextual information."


Almost the solution I need. That last example given is compliant when I want it to be noncompliant. Also, does that rule work with any log implementation or just direct log4j loggers?

All "standard" implementations log4j, log4j2, logback,slf4j, common-log...

Unfortunately this implementation is probably nonstandard, then. loggers are accessed through static Log.level() methods, which internally redirects it to the logger.

IntelliJ has a number of inspections that can work together to more or less achieve what you're looking for. These are under Settings -> Editor -> Inspections.
First under Java -> Logging enable Non-constant string concatenation as argument to logging call to highlight lines that aren't using placeholders as prescribed by the logging framework. There's also a number of other helpful inspections in this category that you might want to enable.
Then under JVM languages -> Logging, enable Number of placeholders does not match number of arguments in logging call. This will highlight lines where there's a mismatch between the number of placeholders and the number of args. This will also highlight ERROR logs whose final arg is an Exception that would be swallowed up by a placeholder (which would log the exception's toString()) rather than provided to the framework (which would appropriately handle stacktraces and such).
To highlight rethrown exceptions that do not wrap the caught exception, look under Java -> Error Handling and enable 'throw' inside 'catch' block which ignores the caught exception. There are likely other useful inspections here as well.
If these are not sufficient, then the SonarLint plugin can highlight some more detailed and opinionated issues related to error logging.
